# How to detect failure from OpenSSL in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

It seems OpenSSL does not return exit codes when there is an error.  For example, ran is not an OpenSSL command (should be "rand"), but the shell result code is still set to zero.  Is there a way to change OpenSSL's behavior here (short of building a custom version)?

For example, this print "ok", "ok", rather than "fail", "ok" as expected:

```
openssl ran 8
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "ok"
else
   echo "fail"
fi
openssl rand 8
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "ok"
else
   echo "fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl ran 8 2>/tmp/err
if [ -s /tmp/err ]
then
  echo fail
else
  echo ok
fi
```

Comment: I was hoping for a configurable way to have openSSL return a non-zero error code.  But, while this feels like a giant hack, it does seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: This will not work with all commands. Eg. "openssl genrsa -out ${PRIVATE_KEY} 2048 2>err.log" will always fill err.log and if will always evaluate to true

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs - good point, thanks.  Seems the solution is still to send the output to a file and analyze that file - either by existence or some other criteria - based on the operation being attempted.